# How can I access the main class object from a function inside the class in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

Please read the 2 comments in the following code.

```
public class Field extends LinearLayout {
    public void init() {
        setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                // I want to access the main object 'Field' here(not the class, the object)
            }
        });

    // to be clear the object referred as 'this' from HERE should be accessed from where the above comment is.
    }
}
```

Is this possible?
Is there a keyword to access the main class object from a function inside the object?

Comment: sorry, I thought the inner class and outer class thing was different from this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should use `Field.this` to access the `Field` instance from within the anonymous class instance.